# jquery mobile alpha 3 links to pages don't work now

Tags: jquery, linker, jquery-mobile

In alpha 2 of jquery mobile, I had this (in test.html):

in the url/address bar it shows this: test.html#pg-one  which makes sense. since I clicked a dialog link.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pg-one">
<a href="test2.html">Row 1<span>test</span></a>
</div>
```

Which loads test2.html  I can use a back button to get back to test.html

However now in jquery alpha 3, when I click the link it tries to access this address:

pg-onetest2.html

???

It seems to be prepending the id of the container div?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Try latest jquery 1.5.1 and report back

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

This is correct behaviour.
jQuery Mobile has the ability to create 'multi-page templates' by stacking multiple divs with a data-role of "page". Each 'page' block needs a unique ID that will be used to link internally between 'pages'. When a link is clicked, the framework will look for an internal 'page' with the ID and transition it into view.
jQuery Mobile uses the hash in combination with the ID to track navigation history for all the Ajax 'pages'.

Comment: I think you misunderstood... OP says that it requests incorrect address.

Comment: I tried 1.5.1 and the same problem occurs.  So just to confirm, in alpha 2 when I linked to test-2.html, it worked fine.  But now (in alpha 3) I need to rename my pages with the prepended id? so now I have to save a page called pg-onetest.html and link to that page?  Seems a bit awkward .